How to update Highcharts data connector linked to DataGrid?
Using Highcharts Dashboards I have created a dataPool with a single data connector that is used by a DataGrid component. Now, I want to update the data in the connector and have that reflected in the DataGrid. I've spent the last hour wrangling this without success. The thing that seems to work is:
dashboard.dataPool.setConnectorOptions({
  id: "my-data",
  options: {
    data: createDataTable(), // returns row-oriented matrix
  },
  type: "JSON"
})

dataGrid.component.load()

However, the load() call is also duplicating event functions that are on the data grid particularly the click event. Thus clicking on a DataGrid row after calling this will call two event handlers.
And in any case, it feels strange to be re-loading a component when it's wired up to a data connector. My question then is either:

How can I update the data connector so that its data is reflected in the DataGrid automatically?
How can I refresh the data grid so that it picks up the current data connector's data table?


UPDATE: I have verified that calling load() on either the component or its data connector (as suggested by @Dominik Chudy) will duplicate events seemingly on purpose:



You should edit the options that data connector uses, and then call connector.load() function.
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/byenxdL6/
function updateData() {
  data.push(["Abc", 600]);
  dash.dataPool.connectors["synchro-data"].load();
}


This works and has the same issue I ran into with my code: the row click event handler isn't disposed of and another one is added for the new row. Presumably because I'm completely refreshing the data and the same row element is used but a new click handler is added

I modified your fiddle to just increment a simple counter when the row is clicked. After updating the data, multiple clicks come through: https://jsfiddle.net/6tfzo5r7/

That's right and it's a bug I'm afraid. But... I have good news: the issue has been resolved in the latest version of the DataGrid, and the release is scheduled for next month. Soon, this problem will be gone in the upcoming version of Highcharts Dashboards.
